# Javascript: convert form to static

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm working on an online application that uses a lot of forms like this:

```
<form action="..." id=".." method="post">
 <label for="i0">something</label>
 <input type="text" id="i0" .... />

 <label for="i1">something</label>
 <select id="i1"..> <option>a</option> <option>b</option> </select>
 .....
 <input type="submit" ...>
</form>
```

I use some JQuery plugins to serialize and deserialize data so I can save all data to database in one JQuery line and fill form with another instruction. My problem now is that in some context I need to show only the data, not editable form.

The question is: is there any JQuery plugin or some code that converts a `<form>` into a textual data preserving the form structure?

Note: a simple option is to show the form and disable all form fields, but this is not a good option if the user wants to print the data.

Comment: You could replace each form control element with a *span* element that has the control's text or value (as appropriate) as its content. But I can't see how it will work effectively for checkboxes and radio buttons, unless all the unchecked ones are removed, leaving only the values or text of the checked ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var html = '';
var $form = $('#form');
$form.find('label').each(function() {
  var $label = $(this);
  html += '<p>' + $label.text() + ': ' + $('#' + $label.attr('for')).val() + '</p>';
})
$form.replaceWith('<div>' + html + '</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing that on submit, you could use [jQuery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started) and the formSerialize() function or beforeSubmit() callback.

```
var queryString = $('#myFormId').formSerialize();
```

or

```
$("#myFormId").ajaxForm({
  beforeSubmit: function(arr, $form, options) {
          // The array of form data takes the following form: 
          // [ { name: 'username', value: 'jresig' }, { name: 'password', value: 'secret' } ] 

          // return false to cancel submit                  

          return true;
  },
  success: function() { 
          //success (your actions here)
  }
});
```

(Use $form).

Answer (score 0):

Here is non-jquery crossbrowser workaround:

```
var getOuterHtml = function(node){
    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
    var clone = node.cloneNode(true);
    wrapper.appendChild(clone);
    var result = wrapper.innerHTML;
    document.body.removeChild(wrapper);
    return result;  
};
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/molecule/THQZf/5/) is working example.

P.S. By the way in ie you can use node.outerHTML.

EDIT: little bit modified example so that it wouldn't remove original form

Answer (score 0):

I would propose a little different, but seems more appopriate solution - [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/)

You keep you common code as template, depending on actual needs, you wrap those templates either to `<forms>` or `<div>`. This is more clear and easy to support.